# ¿Cómo cambiar background-color de un tab / pill / nav con clase .active en bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Si ejecuta el siguiente script verá que por defecto el tab / pill / nav activo tiene clase .active y por tanto el color predeterminado es azul. Dos preguntas:

**1.** ¿Cómo puedo cambiarle ese color activo a otro?

**2.** ¿Puedo aplicarle al tab / pill / nav activo clases .danger (rojo),  .warning (amarillo), ...?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-expanded="true">Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-expanded="true">Messages</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-expanded="true">Settings</a>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-settings-tab">...</div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca debes editar directamente la hoja de estilos `css` de tu `bootstrap`, lo que puedes hacer es crear tu hoja de estilos y acceder a la misma `clase` que usa `bootstrap` y modificar lo que necesites modificar, pero como te digo lo estarías haciendo en una hoja de estilos propia y no en la de la librería:

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.show>.nav-pills .nav-link{
    background: #000000 !important
}
```

Recomiendo el uso de `!important` para que siempre el navegador tome el estilo tuyo y no el de la librería como tal.

Saludos !

Comment: Perfecto! Gracias por una respuesta tan bien elaborada!

Answer (score 2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fijate, pero te recomiendo darle otra clase o id para que no modifiques el bootstrap.css

Comment: Gracias! Si podrias copiar y pegar ese código aquí para que sirva para ¨futuras generaciones¨, te marcaré como respuesta! Gracias !

Comment: fijate la clase que estoy modificando y asi resolveras, yo siempre uso el inspeccionador y es muy util jejejej , salva

Comment: al <a> le agregue otro id en el css llamado miid

Comment: <a class="nav-link active" id="midid" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-expanded="true" style=".nav-pills .nav-link.active, .show>.nav-pills .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff00b5;  }
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(27, 246, 50, 0.81);
">Home</a>


en el css al #id le agregue el codigo 
    background-color: rgba(27, 246, 50, 0.81); por ejemplo